# Joomla: make a component act like a content plugin

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I've created an admin component and now need to insert text on each page of the installing client. So I thought of using the function `onContentPrepare` but it's a method of a `JPlugin` class (a content plugin class to be exact).

Is there a way to invoke the component from the view in the same way like a plugin?

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**: No, you have to write a plugin. But that's not a big thing.

**Long answer**: On each request, exactly *one* component is called. Plugins are triggered at certain events within the control flow. The `onContentPrepare` event is triggered by the components (not from the Joomla! framework), so some components might not support it. Nevertheless, you can get access to the content of any component through plugins anyway - just use the `onAfterRender` event of the system plugins.